# Do I have the correct mental map for adjoint operators for inner product spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, intuition, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $X$, $Y$ be finite dimensional inner product spaces, let $A: X \to Y$ be a linear operator, let $A^*: Y \to X$ be the adjoint operator to the linear operator, defined using $<y, Ax>_Y = <A^*y, x>_X$, $x \in X, y \in Y$ .

We know basic fact that $X,Y$ are partitioned into orthogonal subspaces: Nullspace of A and Range of the Adjoint, so we can come up with the following diagram:

[image]

Can someone check that I have the mapping defined correctly via the above diagram? Is there something I could do that distinguish the operators that map an element to $0$ from the operators that map element to the range?

Is there anything I can do to improve the diagram?

Comment: I prefer to draw $N(A)$ and $R(A^*)$ as one-dimensional orthogonal subspaces on the left, and draw $R(A)$ and $N(A^*)$ as one-dimensional orthogonal subspaces on the right.

Comment: May I venture a tad off-topic and ask what software created such nice figures?

Comment: @Chest Power Point 2013! I was taught to love the PP the hard way when my manager dragged me to his office and showed me the light. I was using Microsoft Visio and Latex before and it took a long time to generate something reasonable. Using PP this figure took me 5 minutes. By the way always use Enhanced Metafile!